# Convert sklearn diabetes dataset into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

How to convert sklearn diabetes dataset into pandas DataFrame?

code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

data = load_diabetes()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sklearn website. You can pass as_frame to specify a pandas dataframe.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes.html

`data = load_diabetes(as_frame=True)`

Comment: But if I do it there is a negative age:  df.age.head()  0.038076       
-0.001882                
          0.085299
             -0.089063
          0.005383

Comment: @Tomer that's true without turning it into the frame. i think you might need to research this dataset a little more before you run it with.